# Spark partitions taking uneven time to execute with frequent executor lost failure

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My spark application processes input CSV file in several stages. At each stage, the **RDD's created are large** in size(in MB's to GB's). I have created different number of partitions and tried but always the partitions complete the stage unevenly. Some partitions finish a stage very soon but last few partitions always take lot of time and keep throwing **heartbeat timeout** and **executor lost failures** and keeps retrying.

I have tried changing the number of partitions to different values but always the last few partitions never complete. I could not fix this issue after trying for long too.

How do I handle this?

Comment: Can you include the code that causes this? Also are you running on YARN, Mesos or in Standalone mode?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt the outputs shown are on YARN..Standalone also causes memory problem and hence executor failures. code available at http://pastebin.com/D7VAVW8U

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the source of the problem is this part:

```
aggregateByKey(Vector.empty[(Long, Int)])(_ :+ _, _ ++ _)
```

Basically what you're doing is a significantly less efficient version of `groupByKey`. If distribution of keys is skewed then distribution after the aggregation will be skewed as and result in uneven load on different machines.

Moreover if data for a single key won't fit into main memory a whole process will fail for the same reason as with `groupByKey`.